# What do the pieces of LaTeX, \left and \right, respectively mean?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

What are their uses and are they even standard?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` are used for delimiters when they have to change the size dynamically depending on the content. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
Compare this:
 \begin{align*}
 \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)^2
            &=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2+2\times\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{
                3}+\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2\\
            &=2+2\sqrt{6}+3\\
            &=5+2\sqrt{6}
\end{align*}
with:
\begin{align*}
 (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2
            &=(\sqrt{2})^2+2\times\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{
                3}+(\sqrt{3})^2\\
            &=2+2\sqrt{6}+3\\
            &=5+2\sqrt{6}
\end{align*}
First one uses \verb|\left(| and \verb|\right)| and second one uses just \verb|(| and \verb|)|. I hope the difference is clear. 

Just another example:    
\[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \qquad (\frac{1}{2})\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this particular case, the `(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})` with `\left` and `\right` gives bit bigger parenthesis making it to look ugly (to some extent) as noted by **Enrico**. In such cases, proper variant of delimiters (`\bigl` and `\bigr` in this case) may be used to get the appropriate height.

For more details, refer to amsmath documentation - page 15, section 4.14 (`texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt). Here is a screen shot of the same:

[image]

Comment: +1 but I think we don't need a blank line between "Just another..." and `\[...`.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: OK As you wish. I am updating :)

Comment: +1; you could point out that in your example with `(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})` the result with `\left` and `\right` is less good than without it (not to say *wrong*).

Comment: @egreg: Yes and added that here also. Thank you :)

Comment: I think there should be a tip when we should use `\left...\right` when we should not use them, with examples. :-)

Comment: The second example (fraction) is way simpler and easier to understand!

Answer (score 39):

`\left` and `\right` are delimiter counterparts and TeX primitives, to be used with so-called "extensible delimiters" in math mode within the same group. This implies two things:

1. If you use one, you have to use the other as well; and
2. They have to be opened/closed at and within the same group level depth.

Common or typical uses include

- `\left\{` ... `\right\}`
- `\left[` ... `\right]`
- `\left(` ... `\right)`

although there is no requirement for the delimiters to be matching. For example, it is fine to use `\left\}`...`\right(`, just as long as you use both `\left` and `\right`. For example (to mimic [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `bmatrix` environment),

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{bmatrix} \qquad
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

If you want to use only one of the two, you still need to include the counterpart, but this time with the argument `.`. That is, either `\left.` or `\right.`, referred to as the null delimiter. TeX inserts a `\nulldelimiterspace` for these.

Extensible delimiters are ones that are comprised of a number of fixed and some variable-length parts. For some eye-candy, here's a visual of an extensible `}`:

[image]

Comment: you will probably not see this but how did you do the eye-candy delimiter thing?

Comment: @Spirit_bird: Look at the code: [`symbol.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/source/symbols.tex). There you'll find the symbols set using `\cmexchar` where `\newcommand{\cmexchar}{\usefont{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}\selectfont\char}`. To see the individual characters, read [How do I know what symbols/characters are available in a font package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131058/5764)