# Wrong Math Symbols - epsilon, varrho

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I'm using the AMSMATH package but I'm getting the wrong representations for the (standard) epsilon and the varrho symbols. I'm not doing anything special.

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, twoside]{book}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Fancy Header

% ********************** OPTIONAL PACKAGES **********************
% --------------------------------- MATH PACKAGES ---------------------------------
    \usepackage{amsmath}    % Math package, for equations, etc.
    \usepackage{amsfonts}   % Math fonts add-in
    \usepackage{amssymb}    % Math symbols add-in
    \usepackage{amsbsy} % Math bold symbols
    \usepackage{amsthm} % Math theorems package
    \usepackage{mathptmx}   % Adobe fonts

%#########################################################
%*
%*  The Document.
%*
\begin{document}

    $\epsilon$ - epsilon [ Wrong Symbol]

    $\varepsilon$ - varepsilon

    $\rho$ - rho

    $\varrho$ - varrho [Wrong Symbol]

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

I'm using TexWorks with MikTex 2.9 and I've confirmed all is up-to-date. Thoughts?

Comment: Please show us this "nothing special" that your doing. Create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile the input and see exactly what you're seeing. For one, you seem to be using a different font, which may be the cause of this.

Comment: Sorry. Reminder to everyone...make a MWE. You may find your problem, like I did. I have a mathptmx package that's conflicting. Got rid of it...problem solved.

Comment: Use `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` instead of `mathptmx`

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about some issue which has not been visible in an MWE but was found by the OP already.

Comment: Hmm. Unclear, perhaps. As answered (and better documented then mine) by @Werner below, it's is on-topic and directed at "Related software and tools"...packages that, in this case conflict. In was unclear because I neglected to put in a MWE. Anyway, will do better next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some fonts change not only the text font, but also the math font. This is the case with [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx). It is possible to [grab a single symbol from another font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764) though:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareSymbolFont{newfont}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}% Computer Modern math font
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Epsilon}{3}{newfont}{15}% Symbol 15
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Varrho}{3}{newfont}{37}% Symbol 37

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  $\Epsilon$ & epsilon \\
  $\varepsilon$ & varepsilon \\
  $\rho$ & rho \\
  $\Varrho$ & varrho
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want to find out where symbols reside within the font, see [How do I know what symbols/characters are available in a font package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131058/5764).

Answer (score 3):

(This answer addresses the query as seen after a major expansion/augmentation took place.)

The first five `\usepackage` statements in the preamble load AMS packages. Then there's the line

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}   % Adobe fonts
```

The `mathptmx` package loads (a clone of) the Times Roman font, with glyphs suitable for both text and math mode. I can't tell if it's a glitch or a feature, but the `mathptmx` package clearly uses the same symbols for `\rho` and `\varrho` as well as for `\epsilon` and `\varepsilon`, respectively.

Which font family do you want to use? If it's Computer Modern, simply don't load the `mathptmx` package. If it's Times Roman, I suggest you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages *instead* of `mathptmx`. That way, you'll get the `\epsilon` and `\varrho` symbols back.

Comment: Palatino? I was quite certain it is Times. `;-)` The Greek letters are taken from Adobe Symbol.

Comment: @egreg - You're absolutely right. Teaches me (yet again) not to write things before having a second cup of coffee in the morning...

Comment: @Mico Well, the *image* he uploaded uses Palatino. So I think it's a more than acceptable mistake.