# How to type \varrho in such a form?

Tags: greek

[image: As shown in the picture, the varrho is larger than the normal form.]

How to type such varrho?

Thanks

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223955/wrong-math-symbols-epsilon-varrho

Comment: What exactly is the question? Which math font family do you use at present?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried what is suggested here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: I have seen the varrho posted above in a journal. It is larger than the usual form and suitable for adding sub- and super-script. But I cannot type it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know which math font, or which font family, is used by the journal from which you excerpted the formula? Lacking this information, it's not likely that speculation as to which math font might be most appropriate will be all that fruitful.

At any rate, the `\varrho` glyph you show looks very much like what's produced by the Computer Modern and Latin Modern math fonts. The following shows the "look" of `\varrho` produced by Latin Modern, XITS (a Times Clone), Asana Math, Cambria Math, and Pagella Math (a Palatino clone), respectively.

[image]

Incidentally, to place "AB" as a subscript after/below `\varrho`, all you need to type is `\varrho_{AB}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=LM]{LM Math}
\setmathfont[version=XITS]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=Asana]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[version=Cambria]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[version=Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{LM} $\varrho$
\mathversion{XITS} $\varrho$
\mathversion{Asana} $\varrho$
\mathversion{Cambria} $\varrho$
\mathversion{Pagella} $\varrho$
\end{document}
```