# Problem with brackets

Tags: brackets

I need to get `{}`. So what is wrong with the command `$ \left\lbrace \left\rbrace  $` ?

Comment: you have two `\left` and no `\right`

Comment: Just being curious, why wouldn't you use `$\{\}$`?

Comment: have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above you have `\left` `\right` not applied correctly. A good answer to the application, you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/what-do-the-pieces-of-latex-left-and-right-respectively-mean). On CTAN, check: [beginlatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beginlatex) – A beginner's guide to LaTeX. This guide, now known as “For­mat­ting in­for­ma­tion”, is a well-re­spected in­tro­duc­tion to the use of LaTeX.

You can manipulate the distance between brackets. With `\left` and `\right` command the clamp is adjusted dynamically. See code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\obeylines
$\{\}$
$\{\,\}$
$\{\:\}$
$\{\;\}$
$\{\quad\}$
$\{\qquad\}$\\
$\{A + B = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} \right]\}$\\
$A+B=\left\{\frac{1}{\frac{a b}{c}}\right\}$\\
$A+B=\left\{\frac{\frac{A+B}{\sin (x)}+1}{A+\frac{C+D}{x^{1/y}}}\right\}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner \obeylines ... smart hint.