# Why do \left and \right add so much extra space under the baseline?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, delimiters

When I write

```
\[
\left \lVert \overrightarrow{\nabla} \right \rVert
\]
```

I get way too much extra space under the baseline:

[image: underbaseline]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: matched delimiters (which is what `\left` and `\right` does) are vertically symmetrical around the math axis (at the height of a minus sign).  this expression, whose height is increased by the overarrow, will gain an equivalent depth using this coding.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for explaining. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Because they ad so much extra space I never use `\left` and `\right` and instead use `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `...` and `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, `...` from [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately, even using `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, which make the `\lVert` and `\rVert` just reach the top of the `\overrightarrow`, similarly add a huge amount of space underneath the baseline in this example. `\bigl` and `\bigr` don't allow the `\lVert` and `\rVert` to reach the top of the `\overrightarrow`.

Comment: @justin Your error is in thinking that the fences should cover the overarrow: they needn't to. Normal fences or `\big` ones are sufficient.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77592/8650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fences are symmetric with respect to the formula axis (the imaginary line where fraction lines sit). In the case of `\overrightarrow{\nabla}`, the size chosen is the same as for `\Bigg`, which extends way down the formula axis.

There's no need that the fences cover the whole construction, in particular the arrow.

Here's a visual sample, where I use the handy `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` function provided by `mathtools` (that loads `amsmath`). I also use smaller arrows as defined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248297/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip1pt}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\norm{\overrightsmallarrow{\nabla}}\quad
\norm[\big]{\overrightsmallarrow{\nabla}}\quad
\norm[\Big]{\overrightsmallarrow{\nabla}}\quad
\norm*{\overrightsmallarrow{\nabla}}
\\
\norm{\overrightsmallarrow{x}}\quad
\norm[\big]{\overrightsmallarrow{x}}\quad
\norm[\Big]{\overrightsmallarrow{x}}\quad
\norm*{\overrightsmallarrow{x}}
\\
\norm{\overrightsmallarrow{X}}\quad
\norm[\big]{\overrightsmallarrow{X}}\quad
\norm[\Big]{\overrightsmallarrow{X}}\quad
\norm*{\overrightsmallarrow{X}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no doubt that the normal version is the right one.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the ialign stuff? I'd just have defined a similar macro using smash and vphantom

Comment: @daleif `\ialign` is just `\halign` with an initialization of `\everycr` to empty and `\tabskip` to zero.

Comment: lost me there ;-), never been that far down TeX.