# I can't change line in equation when I import equation from Mathematica

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking, multline

I copied an equation from Mathematica and I can't change line in the equation but when I write it manually in LaTeX it works fine. Here is the equation that I copied:

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{multlined}
\lambda _3 \sin \left(h_1(t)\right) \sin \left(\cos \left(p_1(t)\right) 
\left(\sqrt{R^2-a^2}     \\    h'(t) sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}
\cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) \sin 
(p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))\right)+p_1(t)\right) 
\left(-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
\cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))-a p'(t) \cos (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) 
\cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))\right)-\lambda _1 \cos
\left(h_1(t)\right) p_1'(t) \left(-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) 
\cos (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))-a p'(t) 
\cos (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) 
\sin (p(t))\right)+\lambda _2 \cos \left(h_1(t)\right) p_1'(t)
\left(\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
\cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) 
\sin (p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))\right)+\frac{1}{2} i 
\left(2 \cos \left(h_1(t)\right) p_1'(t)+2 s_1'(t)\right)
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
```

And what are these `left` and `right`?

Comment: Welcome, the left and right stuff is for dynamically scaled parenthesis. What do you mean with *change line in equation*?

Answer (score 3):

Your line-breaking does not work, since `\left` and `\right` commands have always to come in pairs, on the same line in the output (not necessarily in the tex-file). At the place where you have inserted `\\`, there are four `\left` commands to the left of it, but only two `\right` commands, so you split two `\left`-`\right` pairs.
See ["What do the pieces of LaTeX, \left and \right, respectively mean?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77589/110998) for an explanation of these commands.

Replace `\\` by

```
\right.\right. \\ \left.\left.
```

and it will at least compile without errors. The `\right.` commands close some `\left(` to the left of it, the `\left.` commands are the counterparts of some `\right)`. LaTeX then will measure the height of everything between `\left` and the corresponding `\right` and determine the height of the delimiter (here an opening parenthesis and no closing delimiter, because of the dot after `\right`).

Here is your code structured according to the `\left`s and `\right`s. If you split any of these pairs, you will get an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
  \lambda _3 \sin
  \left ( h_1(t)
  \right) \sin
  \left ( \cos
     \left ( p_1(t)
     \right)
     \left ( \sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}
             \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))+c h'(t)
             \cos (h(t)) \sin (p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))
     \right) +p_1(t)
  \right) 
  \left ( -\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))-a p'(t) \cos (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) 
          \cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))
  \right) -\lambda _1 \cos
  \left ( h_1(t)
  \right) p_1'(t)
  \left ( -\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))-a p'(t) \cos (p(t))+c h'(t)
          \cos (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))
  \right) +\lambda _2 \cos
  \left ( h_1(t)
  \right) p_1'(t)
  \left ( \sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))+c h'(t)
          \cos (h(t)) \sin (p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))
  \right) +\frac{1}{2} i 
  \left (2 \cos
     \left ( h_1(t)
     \right) p_1'(t)+2 s_1'(t)
  \right)
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I suggest to replace `\left(` and `\right)` by fixed-size parentheses like `\big(`, `\Big(`, ... (see ["Big Parenthesis in an Equation"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38870/110998)). After that you can insert line breaks wherever you think it makes sense. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
  \lambda _3 \sin
  \big ( h_1(t)
  \big ) \sin
  \Big ( \cos
     \big ( p_1(t)
     \big )
     \big ( \sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))\\-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}
             \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))\\+c h'(t)
             \cos (h(t)) \sin (p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))
     \big) +p_1(t)
  \Big ) \\
  \big ( -\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))\\-a p'(t) \cos (p(t))+c h'(t) \cos (h(t)) 
          \cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))
  \big ) \\-\lambda _1 \cos
  \big ( h_1(t)
  \big ) p_1'(t)
  \big ( -\sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \cos (p(t))\\-\sqrt{R^2-a^2}
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))-a p'(t) \cos (p(t))\\+c h'(t)
          \cos (h(t)) \cos (p(t))-c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \sin (p(t))
  \big )\\ +\lambda _2 \cos
  \big ( h_1(t)
  \big ) p_1'(t)
  \big ( \sqrt{R^2-a^2} h'(t) \sin (h(t)) \sin (p(t))\\-\sqrt{R^2-a^2} 
          \cos (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))+a p'(t) \sin (p(t))\\+c h'(t)
          \cos (h(t)) \sin (p(t))+c \sin (h(t)) p'(t) \cos (p(t))
  \big )\\ +\frac{1}{2} i 
  \Big (2 \cos
     \big  ( h_1(t)
     \big ) p_1'(t)+2 s_1'(t)
  \Big)
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Bigl( \bigl( \bigr) \Bigr)` better.