# Problem with multline - missing \right)

Tags: multline

I have put the following formula in a latex document but I am getting an error `missing \right`.

```
\begin{multline}
    \int\;\dd^3\vec{x}\int\frac{\dd^3\vec{k^\prime}}{2E(\vec{k}^\prime)(2\pi)^3}
    \left(
        (2\pi)^3\dirac{3}{\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{k}}
        \e{i\dots}a^\dagger(\vec{k}^\prime)\\
        +(2\pi)^3\dirac{3}{\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{k}}
        \e{i\dots}a(\vec{k}^\prime)
    \right)
\end{multline}
```

Note that if I remove the `\\` then it works fine, ie;

```
\begin{multline}
    \int\;\dd^3\vec{x}\int\frac{\dd^3\vec{k^\prime}}{2E(\vec{k}^\prime)(2\pi)^3}
    \left(
        (2\pi)^3\dirac{3}{\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{k}}
        \e{i\dots}a^\dagger(\vec{k}^\prime)
        +(2\pi)^3\dirac{3}{\vec{k}^\prime-\vec{k}}
        \e{i\dots}a(\vec{k}^\prime)
    \right)
\end{multline}
```

That ^^ works.

Comment: Instead of working with `\vphantom`s it is maybe easier to replace `\left(` and `\right)` by parentheses of fixed height, like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333075/110998).