# What is the purpose of "\left.", i.e., "\left" followed by a period?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

What is the purpose of `\left.`, i.e., `\left` followed by a period?
Similarly for `\right`.

E.g. for `\right.` and `\left` (no period)

```
begin{eqnarray}\label{Dsys}
  \textcolor[rgb]{.25,.0,.8}{%
    \left\{\begin{array}{l}
              u_t=F(u) \\ \\ 
              u(0)=u_0\in H,
           \end{array}
     \right. 
  }
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Off-topic/aside: [Don't use eqnarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). It's badly deprecated. Much better alternatives are readily available.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think you would need to point to a duplicate answer _here_ (there probably is one) almost every question could be closed if "read the manual" was an acceptable close reason.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - A search for the `Missing delimiter (. inserted)` warning message brings up (at least) 76 "hits". (Most of these hits are related to users either forgetting to provide a suitable fence symbol or to forgetting that curly braces must be entered as `\{` and `\}` and hence expressing surprise that `\left{ ... \right}` doesn't generate the intended output.) Somewhat to my surprise, I couldn't find an earlier question that asked directly what `\left.` and/or `\right.` do...

Comment: Closing this question goes against the grain of the desire to make Stack Overflow and the entire Stack Exchange network [a more welcoming place](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). Marking as a duplicate of a question asking for books is downright insulting. This question has a short and simple answer; it does not require a book.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77589/15925

Comment: @Mico Has eqnarray been officially deprecated by the Latex team and "powers that be", or there is just a wide consensus that it is a bad idea to use it?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - Not being a member of the LaTeX team, I'm afraid I have no special knowledge of what's "officially deprecated" or not. (Suggestion: Ask Frank Mittelbach, David Carlisle, and/or Joseph Wright about their views...) For sure, there's a widespread consensus -- actually, make that a unanimous view -- that it's a bad idea to keep using `eqnarray`. However, since `eqnarray` and `eqnarray*` are mentioned in Leslie Lamport's textbook, and since people still cite that book, it's probably infeasible to officially deprecate these wretched environments.

Comment: @Mico I asked this because you used the word "deprecated" in your comment --- that word is usually reserved for something that has officially declared obsolete by the developers (and will likely be removed in future versions), in my experience.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - I see. Indeed, the term "deprecated" may have created the false impression that I was speaking with some kind of official authority. That wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 33):

I assume you're familiar with the most common use case for `\left` and `\right`, which is to provide automatic sizing of visual delimiters or "fences" -- round parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, angle-brackets, vertical bars, etc -- so that the "fences" may visually enclose the material they surround. Example:

```
\[ \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) \]
```

Well, sometimes a "one-sided fence" is called for. The example code you provided is such a case: we need a large curly brace to the left of the `array`, but nothing to the right of the `array`. To cater to such needs, TeX lets you "pair" the `\left\{` statement with a `\right.` statement. If you will, the "`.`" symbol after `\right` denotes "no fence on this side". Because `\left` and `\right` must occur in pairs and need to operate on *something*, it wouldn't work to write `\right` *without* a suitable argument. (As explained below, LaTeX issues a warning message if no suitable argument is encountered.) Similarly, there may be cases for which one needs to "pair" a `\left.` directive with a `\right|` directive, as in

```
\[ \left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right|_{x=x_0} \]
```

Aside: In case you're wondering *how* TeX goes about processing the material that immediately follows `\left` and `\right`, here's a TeXnical explanation. As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, TeX assigns a "delimiter code" (`\delcode` for short) to all (math-mode) tokens: "fence symbols" -- such as round parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, and vertical bars -- have a positive `\delcode`, the `.` ("dot", "period", "full stop") symbol has a `\delcode` of zero, and all other tokens have `-1` as their `\delcode`. If the token that follows `\left` or `\right` has a positive `\delcode`, i.e., if a "real" fence symbol is to be processed, the fence is sized according to TeX's algorithms; if the `\delcode` is zero, nothing is done (apart from the insertion of a bit of horizontal whitespace); and if the `\delcode` is negative, TeX issues a

```
Missing delimiter (. inserted)
```

warning message. This message should be taken seriously, i.e., one should examine the code and fix it appropriately. For more information on `\delcode`s, do peruse Chapter 17 of The TeXbook, entitled "More about Math", and especially the second double-dangerous-bend material on p. 156. For still more information, please check out pages 290 and 345 of The TeXbook.

Incidentally, the `amsmath` package provides an environment called `cases` which is designed to typeset your example code in a way that focuses on the *meaning* of what you're writing, without distractions about *how* one should go about implementing the typesetting chore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{Dsys}
\textcolor[rgb]{.25,.0,.8}{%
   \begin{cases}
       u_t=F(u)    \\ 
       u(0)=u_0\in H
   \end{cases} 
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The special status of `.` comes from the fact its `\delcode` is 0; “true” fences have positive `\delcode`, all other characters have `\delcode` set to −1.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for mentioning the `\delcode` system; I've updated my answer to provide an entire paragraph on this topic.

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about delimiters and `\delcode`, another good reference is section 21.2, "Delimiters", on pp. 191f. of Victor Eijkhout's book *TeX by Topic*. (Type `texdoc texbytopic` to bring up a copy of this document.)

Comment: After `\left` or `\right` one can also have `\delimiter`; indeed, macros such as `\lceil` are defined as `\delimiter"4264306` (after `\delimiter` one should have a 28 bit integer).

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. Let's see if the OP (or anyone else...) posts a follow-up query about what's allowed/expected to follow `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: THANK YOU Mico That completely answered my question.  Thanks to others who posted helpful comments too.

Comment: @peter - You're most welcome! If you feel like this answer has been fully helpful, please feel free to "accept" it by clicking on the "checkmark" symbol along the upper-left edge of the answer. ;-)